# Image saved to server appears blank

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to save the canvas as an image onto my server, I have accomplished this and the script saves a jpeg file and the file has a size(so something is in it), however when I view it,  it shows up as a black background with no picture on it, does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
document.getElementById('rasterize').onclick = function (){     
            var image = canvas.toDataURL();                     
            var xmlHttpReq = false;       
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
           ajax.open('POST', 'save3.php', false);
           ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
           ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                console.log(ajax.responseText);
            }
           ajax.send("imgData="+image);

        };
```

PHP

```
  <?php

define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
$data = $_POST['imgData'];

$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpeg';

$uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);

file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($uri));

echo $file;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default format for `toDataURL()` is image/png. If your php script expects a jpg image, you will need to specify it with `toDataUrl('image/jpeg', 0.8)` where 0.8 is your image quality.

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL(); //outputs png
```

vs

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8); //outputs jpeg
```

Comment: I have already tried the default format by changing  the PHP and script to png, but it results the same, image with black background.